# How to place this div at the bottom of the document?

Tags: css, html

The `document` has a structure like this :

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            content here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <div class="nav-bar-inner padding10" >
                <span style="text-align: center;" >
                    2015, XXX &copy; by <a class="fg-color-white" href="mailto:xxx@xxx.com">XXX</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

`CSS` are these :

```
.metrouicss {
}
.metrouicss .page {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.metrouicss .page {
    width: 940px ;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.metrouicss .nav-bar {
  background-color: #2d89ef;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.metrouicss .nav-bar .nav-bar-inner {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.padding10 {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

At runtime the `<div class="page">` after the content is just below the content ! I want it to be at the bottom of the document. How to do that ?

Comment: declare `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` for `.page`

Comment: Avoid inline styling (`style=...`) when you can do that in CSS.

Comment: It sounds like you need a "sticky footer". Depending on your actual requirements (what if the content fills the page, for instance) there are various options available. Try searching SO for "sticky footer"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial how to keep block at the bottom of the page  http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Basically you just need to add a few styles to your block :

```
.metrouicss .page {
   position : absolute;
   bottom : 0;
}
```

Comment: please take a look here, that is your example, http://jsfiddle.net/r035mqy2/

in yout html you don't have class **metrouicss** so I have removed it from css styles for page, also in this case height: 100%; and min-height: 100%; won't work, so also removed. What do you want to make with them? we can find another solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a few empty divs in between, you could add bottom margins under the content or top margins where the mail link div is.